# IOS: Code signing error Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I updated to Xcode 6.3.1 and am using an Ipod touch that is registered with Apple as a developer with IOS 8.3 installed. I am getting the code signing error. This seems to be a common problem, so I closed the Xcode and reopened it. Deleted all the provisioning profiles and refreshed it on Xcode. I am still not able to fix the problem.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Please find the snap shot of the error below.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The problem was resolved by using automatic in the provision profile instead of using the actual profile name